# Error running Django server, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.myapp'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am trying to deploy a django project using PyCharm, I have read basically all the method and kept trying, but none of those can help me with this error, I must lost some important concept here.

This my project structure:

```
C:.
│  db.sqlite3
│  manage.py
│  __init__.py
│
├─myapp
│  │  admin.py
│  │  apps.py
│  │  models.py
│  │  serializers.py
│  │  tests.py
│  │  views.py
│  │  __init__.py
│  │
│  ├─migrations
│  │      __init__.py
│  │
│  └─__pycache__
├─mysite
│  │  asgi.py
│  │  settings.py
│  │  urls.py
│  │  wsgi.py
│  │  __init__.py
│  │
│  └─__pycache__
└─__pycache__
```

And this is my print out of command in `sys.path`:

```
(web system) C:\Users\wisdo\web system\mysite>python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 
'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\python38.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system', 
'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\lib\\site-packages']
```

The `urls.py` code：

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from mysite.myapp import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'group', views.GroupViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/',include('rest_frameword.urls'), namespace='rest_framework'),
]
```

The `views.py` code：

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from mysite.myapp.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer
# Create your views here.

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by("-date_joined")
    """
    date_jointed：紀錄Users建立的時間
    A datetime designating when the account was created.
    Is set to the current date/time by default when the account is created.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows group to be viewed or edited
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

The Error log :

```
(web system) C:\Users\wisdo\web system\mysite>python manage.py runserver

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

['C:\\Users\\wisdo\\web system\\mysite', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3
\\envs\\web system\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:/Users/wisdo/web system/mysite/mysite']
['C:\\Users\\wisdo\\web system\\mysite', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3
\\envs\\web system\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system', 'C:\\Users\\wisdo\\anaconda3\\envs\\web system\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:/Users/wisdo/web system/mysite/mysite',
'C:/Users/wisdo/web system/mysite/mysite']
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\anaconda3\envs\web system\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\web system\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    from mysite.myapp import views
  File "C:\Users\wisdo\web system\mysite\myapp\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mysite.myapp.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.myapp'
```

From the idea in the command below, I tried:

```
#change the source of directory
from mysite.myapp import views
from myapp.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer
#into
from myapp import views
from myapp.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer
```

Also this warning happened in both of command line:
[image]

Then I checked my root directory and Add mysite to Source Folder:

[image]

add a Source Folder.

[image]

and every goes fine, I can deploy the server now. ;) Keep going practice the Django REST framework!

[image]

Comment: You use `from myapp import views`

Comment: i'm sorry, but it's still returns error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python path is normally set to the root directory here. This means that you import the `views` module as:

```
from myapp import views
```

and:

```
from myapp.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer
```

so *without* a `mysite.` prefix.

Comment: @LerryZhang: you did this both in the `urls.py` and `views.py`... Perhaps even on more locations.